# I am trying to write a python code to get the perspective out of the input image using OpenCV. How to get rid of this error that comes?

Tags: opencv

This code is about warping the given image and detecting the circular shaped objects (checkers) in the image using hough transfom.

Input files for my code below

1. [This is the input image used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuSjp.jpg)

2. A JSON file having the required dimensions used to calculate the perspective.

   {
   "canonical_board": {
   "tl_tr_br_bl": [
   [
   622,
   85
   ],
   [
   1477,
   66
   ],
   [
   1420,
   835
   ],
   [
   674,
   837
   ]
   ],
   "bar_width_to_checker_width": 0.716,
   "board_width_to_board_height": 1.03,
   "pip_length_to_board_height": 0.36
   }
   }

**My code**

```
#import necessary packages

import cv2
import json
import numpy as np

from operator import itemgetter
from glob import glob


#load file

input_file=open('3913.jpg.info.json', 'r')

json_decode = json.load(input_file)

result = []

result.append(json_decode['canonical_board']['tl_tr_br_bl'])

result.append(json_decode['canonical_board']['bar_width_to_checker_width'])

result.append(json_decode['canonical_board']['board_width_to_board_height'])

result.append(json_decode['canonical_board']['pip_length_to_board_height'])

print("tl_tr_br_bl:",result[0])
print("bar_width_to_checker_width:",result[1])
print("board_width_to_board_height",result[2])
print("pip_length_to_board_height",result[3])

normal_img = cv2.imread('3913.jpg')

pts1 = np.float32([[454, 83], [1240, 79], [1424, 808], [275, 842]])

pts2 = np.array([[0.397],[0.986],[0.402]], dtype=np.float32)

M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1.astype(np.float32), pts2)
         
dst = cv2.warpPerspective(normal_img, M, (1300, 800))

#perspective of the original image shown
cv2.imshow(dst)


#converting the image into grayscale

gray = cv2.cvtColor(dst, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#locating the circles using hough transform

# detect circles in the image
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.2, 100)

# ensure at least some circles were found
if circles is not None:
    
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

    no_of_circles = len(circles)

# loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
    for (x, y, r) in circles:
        
        cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
        cv2.imshow("output", np.hstack([image, output]))
        cv2.waitKey(0)
    
#number of circles

        print("number of circles detected-",no_of_circles)
```

**Error I am getting**

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-efcd2ec83d0c> in <module>
     37 pts2 = np.array([[0.397],[0.986],[0.402]], dtype=np.float32)
     38 
---> 39 M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1.astype(np.float32), pts2)
     40 
     41 dst = cv2.warpPerspective(normal_img, M, (1300, 800))

error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:3391: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.checkVector(2, CV_32F) == 4 && dst.checkVector(2, CV_32F) == 4 in function 'getPerspectiveTransform'
```

Comment: Why are your pts2 float values less than 1?  I think you must have integer values. So you may need to scale your dst coordinate system. The output image dtype must be the same as the input. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87

Comment: Sure, but could you suggest any change in the code that should be made to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

your pts2 array is wrong. it needs to be four points, not three. and the points need to be two-dimensional, not one-dimensional.